# Loop through the files one by one in a directory as they appear and display result of command executed on them on the screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a directory in which new files appear  at a certain interval (10-15 seconds), all the files are in the same format (.ffid) and also numbered in a regular manner `(1.ffid 2.ffid 3.ffid)`, I wand to execute some commands to extract information from n and (n-1) file and perform calculation on that information and display it on screen while the script runs.

This is the code that I have right now :

```
#!/bin/bash
#bash-hexdump
# Quick script to check delay of the shotpoints 

echo "please enter the complete line name as mentioned in the RAID2"

read  line

cd /argus/raid2/$line

dir=/argus/raid2/$line/

FILES="$dir"
while [ true ] 

do 


FFID=$(ls -lrt "$FILES" | grep -i ffid | tail -1)

echo "FFID Value is : "$FFID""


while [ $FFID = $(ls -lrt "$FILES" | grep -i ffid | tail -1) ]

do 

sleep 0.5

done 





ls -lrt "$dir" | awk '{print "     "$9}' | awk 'NR>1' | head -n -2 > /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_a


ls -lrt "$dir" | awk '{print "     "$9}' | awk 'NR>2' | head -n -2 > /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_b


paste /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_a  /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_b > /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_c




rm /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_a  /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_b



let ofst1=1840

let ofst2=1974

let ofst3=1798



 while    read  cffid nffid

 do 




        wd=$(hexdump -s $ofst1 -n 6 -e "64 \"%_p\" \"\\n\"" "$FILES""$cffid")  

        sp=$(hexdump -s $ofst3 -n 4 -e "64 \"%_p\" \"\\n\"" "$FILES""$cffid")  

        ct=$(hexdump -s $ofst2 -n 8 -e "64 \"%_p\" \"\\n\"" "$FILES""$cffid" | awk -F: '{print ($1 *3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3}')  

         nt=$(hexdump -s $ofst2 -n 8 -e "64 \"%_p\" \"\\n\"" "$FILES""$nffid" | awk -F: '{print ($1 *3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3}')  


          wbt=$(echo "$wd" | awk '{print (($1) *1.33)/1000}' | cut -c 1-3)

          spint=$(echo "$nt" "$ct" | awk '{print $1 - $2}') 

            tot=$(echo "$wbt" "$spint" | awk '{print $1 + $2}' |cut -c 1-2) 



          echo "  "  "    SP_NO  "  " "  "W_d"   "      "                                      "  Current_SP_Time "         "    "       "  Next_SP_Time  "      " W_B_T "          " SP_Int "           "   "            "  Total_time "  

          echo " "

          echo " " "  "  "  $sp "     "  $wd "         ""    "  "  "      "       " $ct "   "          "        "  $nt "         "   "    "   "  " $wbt   "          "  $spint "      "     "      "    "        "   $tot "     ""

          echo "                                                                                                                                                                           "



          echo " " 

          if [ $tot -lt 12 ] 

          then 

                paste /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/slow_down.txt 

                echo please slow down 



           fi

                done < /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_c 




   done
```

But it outputs repeated values from list_c , is there any way to just display the output line by line when new files appear in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Decide how you want to see which files have been processed:
You can write the filenames of the processed files to a logfile or move them to another dir (`mkdir -p processed; mv ${file} processed`).
Process the new files and sleep a short time:

```
function process_file {
   your_logic_with $1
}

while [ x ]; do
   for file in *.ffid; do
      # grep "^${file}$" logfile | continue
      process_file "${file}"
      # mv "${file}" processed
      # Or
      # echo "${file}" >> processed
   done
   sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use **inotify** to monitor newly created files.

In your case, to output (or do whatever you want) with newly created `.ffid` files :

```
DIR="/tmp" # set DIR with your dir to monitor

inotifywait -m -e create $DIR | while read file
do
  if [[  ${file##*.} == "ffid" ]]; then
    if [[ -n "$prev_file" ]]; then
      printf "Command on previous file: %s\n" "$prev_file";
    fi
    if [[ -n "$file" ]]; then
      printf "Command on last file: %s\n" "$file";
    fi
    prev_file=$file  # stores the penultimate created file
  fi
done
```

Comment: How to get inotify , is it inbuilt?

Comment: You can get it with `apt-get install inotify-tools`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without inotify.

Comment: I am on a vessel and don't have administrative rights to use sudo, in short I can't install the package ...kind of stuck

Answer (score 0):

> But it outputs repeated values …

You get repeated output for the same file because you have the setting

```
FFID=$(ls -lrt "$FILES" | grep -i ffid | tail -1)
```

of the old FFID value (to be compared with present ones to check if a new one has appeared) inside your outer `while [ true ]` loop, thus getting the same "old" value repeatedly. Rather move that line before the outer loop and set the variable `FFID` in the loop to the new FFID, using that for the comparison in the next loop cycle.